# Convert MySQL UTC datetime to UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

These both correctly return the current UNIX timestamp:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LOCALTIMESTAMP()); #MySql
echo time(); //PHP
```

But I'm storing UTC_TIMESTAMPs in my database (not LOCALTIMESTAMPs).

How can I convert a UTC datetime to a UNIX timestamp using MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Note that LOCALTIMESTAMP() is a synonym for NOW().  So what you're really asking is how to get the current time and convert it to GMT and then convert to a unix timestamp to store in the db.  So this will work:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@global.time_zone, 'GMT'));
```

As an aside, it's always much better to use the time and date columns of a database rather than unix timestamps.  It makes querying and displaying results much easier.

Update: Are you sure you are getting what you think you are?  [UNIX_TIMESTAMP returns a UTC based seconds since the UNIX epoch](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).  It does not return a [MySQL DateTime type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html).  If you have an actual UTC DateTime instance, then you can put that directly into your DateTime column of your database and don't have to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP as an intermediary.  What type do you actually have that's in local time?

Comment: I'm not storing timestamps in my table. UNIX_TIMESTAMP() returns a datetime, which I'm storing in a datetime column in my table. I'm wondering how to get a unix timestamp from my utc datetime.

Comment: No vote down at all, but epoch timestamps in a DB have solved numerous date arithmetic and management problems for many schemas in which I've worked.  I would not necessarily shy away from them.