# Read MySQL datetime as Unix time

Tags: mysql, datetime, utc, unix-timestamp

I have a table with a `datetime` column. Into this column I have written UTC dates using `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`. Now, from PHP, I want to get this UTC date as an unix timestamp. How?

I know of the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function. I'm not sure it's reliable since it uses local time zone and stuff. I just want a pure conversion from the UTC datetime to the number of seconds since 1970...

Comment: see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548780/convert-mysql-utc-datetime-to-unix-timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you'd use `strtotime()`.

**Edit:** `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` uses local time zones when converting data stored as `timestamp` not data stored as `datetime`. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html.

As you're using `datetime`, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` should be safe.

Comment: So there is no way to accomplish this in MySQL?

Comment: You can just use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. I believe the issue with timezones is for data stored as `timestamp` type, not `datetime` type as you use: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html -- I'll add this to my answer

Comment: Important detail indeed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_field) as timestamp
FROM table
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp